# tikz drawing label between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am drawing TCP packet diagram and I have been using coordinates to draw my packets and to place the socket end points (IP:port) on my diagram.

I now need to include the TCP packet type.  I would like to centre this between the two (IP:port) SYN (IP:port) in the diagram like this. (Ignore _)

192.168.11.10:37064__________________SYN________________10.17.84.113:2222

<------------------------------------------------------------------------

Is the a way to center text between two nodes or should I change the way I draw the TCP flow?

This code snipet is how I have been drawing my packets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (p1a) at (13.5,7.0);
\coordinate (p1b) at (7.5,7.0);
\draw [->] (p1a) -- (p1b);
\node [anchor=east, label={[anchor=east, font=\tiny\sffamily]above:10.17.84.113:2222}] at (p1a.east) {};
\node [anchor=west, label={[anchor=west, font=\tiny\sffamily]above:192.168.11.10:37064}] at (p1b.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean `\draw [->] (p1a) --node {foo } (p1b);` ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in the following manner:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% define the nodes directly
\node [  font=\tiny\sffamily] (p1a) at (13.5,7) {10.17.84.113:2222};
\node [ left = 3cm of p1a,  font=\tiny\sffamily] (p1bwest) (p1b) at (7.5,7.0) {192.168.11.10:37064};
%% now draw the lines
\draw [->] ([yshift=-5mm]p1a.south east) -- ([yshift=-5mm]p1b.south west);
\draw (p1a.south west) -- node[anchor=base,fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily]{SYN} (p1b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the `-5mm` in `yshift` suitably. I assumed that the `SYN` comes on the line. If not, remove the option `anchor=base` and put `above` instead.